# C# Forms.DataVisualization.Charting -> Zoom on X axis not work

Tags: c#, charts, zooming

I have made a simple candlestick chart with the `WinForms.Datavisualation` Chart, now I try to add zoom functionality to it but it won't work on the X axis.

X Axis got DateTime as Type, Y are floats, I setup the zoom equally to the Y axis.

```
ca.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
ca.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
ca.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;

ca.AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
ca.CursorY.AutoScroll = true;
ca.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

But I just can zoom on Y Axis, any idea?

[Chart Zoom Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xjHU.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562629/zooming-selection-not-working-for-c-sharp-chart-with-x-axis-of-the-type-time Have you seen this

Comment: _X Axis got DateTime as Type_ Do use the debugger to check the actual x-values in the points!!